# Difference of two lists C#

Tags: c#, list, set-difference

I have two lists of strings both of which are ~300,000 lines.  List 1 has a few lines more than List 2.  What I'm trying to do is find the strings that in List 1 but not in List 2.

Considering how many strings I have to compare, is `Except()` good enough or is there something better (faster)?

Comment: It's only a problem if you've noticed performance degradation. Performance questions can really only be answered by you, since only you know what "too slow" is for your application. Consider the end user, target platform, etc.

Comment: if duplicate lines isn't a problem, you could use HashSet and Contains method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx

Comment: moving from list to hash table and then just using contains seems like a great way to quickly attain very close to optimal performance

Comment: [IEnumerable/List.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) *already uses* a [Hash]Set internally (which is why it doesn't guarantee ordering and uses `IEquatable`) for standard List .. just use it (as it has a pretty good Big-O) and *then* see if anything needs to be done ..

Comment: (Oops, I mean IEqualityComparer and not IEquatable.)

Comment: I've had very good results with linq `Except()` re-factoring an application which was taking > 6 hours down to less than 10 mins.  Don't be scared of `Except()` it is amazing.

Comment: For 2 lists you should be fine with an in-memory data structure.  If you are running a web application where each user submits their words you would probably run into memory issues. But if its only 2 lists I'd say keep it simple and use HashSets.

Comment: @pst using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch I can see that HashSet is slower to create the list, but faster to excute Except()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally the enumerable `Except` extension method uses `Set<T>` to perform the computation. It's going to be as least as fast as any other method.

Go with `list1.Except(list2)`.

It'll give you the best performance and the simplest code.

Comment: As Jonathan poins out, it *might* make sense to use a HashSet for one (or both) of the lists as then `Except` can avoid having to create the immediate [Hash]Sets .. of course, this would imply that the original data ordering is not important, duplicates are not allowed, and that the difference was executed enough times for it to matter ..

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
    HashSet<String> hash1 = new HashSet<String>(new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" });
    HashSet<String> hash2 = new HashSet<String>(new string[] { "a", "b" });
    List<String> result = hash1.Except(hash2).ToList();
```