# Compare 2 lists of objects and create a new list based off item properties in the first list not being present in the second with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq, compare

I'm trying to compare 2 lists and create a new list of the first list based on its item properties not being present on the second. Sorry if this is badly worded, I'll try and demonstrate below

I have 2 lists:

```
public IList<OrderList> OrderList { get; set; }
public IList<ApplicationUser> UserList { get; set; }
```

and a 3rd list:

```
public IList<ApplicationUser> NoOrders { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to populate the 3rd list with objects from "UserList" where the FK Id field if not present in the "OrderList". Creating a list of users who have not ordered.

The code i'm trying to use is:

```
NoOrders = UserList.Where(y => OrderList.Any(z => z.ApplicationUserId != 
y.id.ToString())).ToList();
```

I've also tried to create lists of the classes directly with:

```
NoOrders = await _db.ApplicationUser.Include(u => u.OrderRequest).Where(i 
=> i.id != OrderRequest.ApplicationUserId.ToString()).ToListAsync();
```

Sadly I've had no luck with either method. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks, 
I really appreciate it

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to include sample inputs in the [mcve] **as well as expected results for those sample inputs**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference of two lists C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963427/difference-of-two-lists-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

I think your first try is on track:

Try this:

```
NoOrders = UserList.Where(y => OrderList.All(z => z.ApplicationUserId != 
y.id.ToString())).ToList();
```

or

```
NoOrders = UserList.Where(y => !OrderList.Any(z => z.ApplicationUserId == 
y.id.ToString())).ToList();
```

You were checking whether there are any orders which don't match the user ID when what you really want to make sure is that there are no orders which do.